# Android FTPClient code is not uploading file from sdcard to FTP server

Tags: android, ftp-client

I was working on android FtpClient which is not uploading any file from the sdcard to the FTPServer and is not throwing any exception so i couldn't see any error on this code please someone help me to fix this

**code**

```
Button upload=(Button)findViewById(R.id.upload);
upload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "upload");
            final String FPATH = fileLocal.getPath();
            Filename filename = new Filename(FPATH, '/', '.');
            System.out.println("Extension = " + filename.extension());
            System.out.println("Filename = " + filename.filename());
            System.out.println("Path = " + filename.path().replace("/mnt/", ""));
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------");

            System.out.println("srcFilePath = " + fileLocal.getPath());
            System.out.println("desFileName = " +  filename.filename()+"."+filename.extension());
            System.out.println("desDirectory = " + "/");


            ftpClient.ftpUpload(fileLocal.getPath().replace("/mnt/", ""), filename.filename()+"."+filename.extension(),"/", monContext);
            //Refresh list

            uploadRefresh();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("sarath:from upload");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

this is my **logcat**

```
02-24 15:51:00.320: I/System.out(12279): --------------------------------------------------------------
02-24 15:51:00.320: I/System.out(12279): srcFilePath = /mnt/sdcard/b.class
02-24 15:51:00.320: I/System.out(12279): desFileName = b.class
02-24 15:51:00.320: I/System.out(12279): desDirectory = /
02-24 15:51:00.344: D/UploadActivity(12279): List directory of server1 : /
02-24 15:51:00.344: D/UploadActivity(12279): recuperation des données du repertoires
02-24 15:51:00.391: D/UploadActivity(12279): liste des repertoire : $RECYCLE.BIN
02-24 15:51:00.391: D/UploadActivity(12279): liste des repertoire : Android
02-24 15:51:00.391: D/UploadActivity(12279): liste des repertoire : Juno
02-24 15:51:00.391: D/UploadActivity(12279): liste des repertoire : Juno.rar
02-24 15:51:00.391: D/UploadActivity(12279): liste des repertoire : KodSpider Workspace
02-24 15:51:00.399: D/UploadActivity(12279): liste des repertoire : System Volume Information
02-24 15:51:00.399: D/UploadActivity(12279): nombre de file dans le repertoire : 6
02-24 15:51:00.399: I/UploadActivity(12279): Directory : $RECYCLE.BIN
02-24 15:51:00.399: I/UploadActivity(12279): Directory : Android
02-24 15:51:00.399: I/UploadActivity(12279): Directory : Juno
02-24 15:51:00.399: I/UploadActivity(12279): File : Juno.rar
02-24 15:51:00.399: I/UploadActivity(12279): Directory : KodSpider Workspace
02-24 15:51:00.399: I/UploadActivity(12279): Directory : System Volume Information
```

Comment: please write some output for system.out.p....

Comment: see my edit it includes the file listing..

Comment: please comment in english..

Comment: try this http://androidexample.com/FTP_File_Upload_From_Sdcard_to_server/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=98&aaid=120

and let me know after analyse this

Comment: yes this example works perfect..

Comment: But the files uploaded using this project is corrupted...

Comment: please update your code whatever you have did

Comment: Actually i solved i... by setting the file type as binary when it is downloading and uploading...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try This Example : 
[FTP Example](http://androidexample.com/FTP_File_Upload_From_Sdcard_to_server/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=98&aaid=120)

It will getting you exact idea for how to implement FTP functionality.